# How to filter results in a select statement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on setting up a small site for users to log in and post messages.  I'm in the process of setting up a table that stores contacts (so that users can view and send messages to each other on the board).  I'm almost done configuring it but have run into a roadblock.

```
 When a user registers for the first time, an entry is created in each of two tables; users and contacts.  The users table stores username and password stuff, the contacts table stores a directory of people on the system and whether they've been added to other people's contact lists.  The tables look like this;

mysql> select userid, firstname, lastname, username from users;
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
| userid | firstname | lastname | username |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
|     63 | Chris     | Smith    | csmith   |
|     64 | Susan     | Smith    | ssmith   |
|     65 | Roger     | Smith    | rsmith   |
|     66 | Diane     | Smith    | dsmith   |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from contacts;
+----------+---------+-----------+
| username | contact | confirmed |
+----------+---------+-----------+
| csmith   | csmith  | 0         |
| ssmith   | ssmith  | 0         |
| rsmith   | rsmith  | 0         |
| dsmith   | dsmith  | 0         |
| csmith   | dsmith  | 2         |
| dsmith   | csmith  | 2         |
| dsmith   | ssmith  | 1         |
| dsmith   | rsmith  | 1         |
+----------+---------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Users are able to authenticate, they're able to add and remove each other with no problem.  The "confirmed" column stores the state of the contacts. 0 is used to indicate the initial entry in contacts made for the user upon registration.  1 indicates if an invite has been sent from username to contact but has not been confirmed yet.  2 indicates that the contact has been confirmed.  By doing a select query on different parts of the site, I can show the user's contact list or just a list of people on the system they MAY add but haven't yet.  Almost everything works fine except for the directory list of uninvited contacts.

The initial list of contacts should be composed of a select query's output for users that have a confirmed state of 0, it should omit the user's own entry (so, they shouldn't be adding themselves let's say), and (the part that's vexing me), it should also omit anyone with a confirmation of 1 (invitation sent) or 2 (contact confirmed) with their own username.

So, csmith should see in his directory of users ssmith and rsmith but should not see dsmith because dsmith has already been added to his contacts (confirmation of 2 at 5th entry in contacts).

So, I have been having a hard time thinking of a way to wright a query for directory lookups given these rules.  How can I create a rule that does;

`select contact from contacts where username!=$authenticated_user and confirmation='0'`

this will give me list of users on the system except my own, people who've not been invited yet.

but then also pulls out

```
select contact from contacts where username=$authenticated_user and confirmation='1' and confirmation='2'
```

from the output so that the list of already invited and/or added users doesn't show up any more?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `contact`
FROM test.test
WHERE `contact` 
NOT IN 
    (SELECT `contact` 
    FROM test.test
    WHERE `username` = "csmith");
```

Any entry for mutual friendships is given in the format (a -> b) and (b -> a), all invites are given in the format (a -> b) simplifying the testing - we just have to look for any user who doesn't have $username (p.ex. "csmith") as username in a contact entry.

(This also does exclude the user who is by default connected to himself via (a,a,0).)

Comment: No, this doesn't fix the problem but I think it's on the right track.  I have a questions about this syntax.  When I read it, my impression is that it's trying to say, "select usernames from the table if they are not part of the output of the subquery", correct?  Am I able to add multiple subqueries to this?

Comment: you are, but i would suggest reading up on that topic first, it may result in horrible performance -- i am really interested what exactly didn't work for you, judging from a test-case and by logic i would expect it to fullfill your requirements, would you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, and thank you for asking - I didn't want to burden you too much.  Here's what happens under the hood.  Assume 3 users; csmith, dsmith, and rsmith.  They all have entries in the user table and when they originally registered, an entry was made in the contacts table in the form of username, username, 0 (if the user's name is csmith, it would look like "csmith, csmith, 0".)  This entry is needed, in

Comment: my mind, because they need to be in the directory from the begining so that others can find them (and if there's a better way of doing this, I'd be excited to hear about it.)  Anyway, when another user (let's say dsmith) finds csmith, they can click on a link to request permission to add them.  This creates an entry of username, contact, confirmation (so, the entry would be "dsmith, csmith, 1).  1

Comment: signifies that a request to add a contact has been sent but has not been accepted yet.  When csmith sees this pop up on his screen, he can click confirm, which in turn makes that entry dsmith, csmith, 2 ("2" signifying that the contact has been added to the user's list.  So, there are a couple of things happening here.  1) The entry of username, username, 0 never changes.  It stays unchanged.  This entry

Comment: must show up in the user's directory only if the user has not been requested for confirmation or is not part of the user's contact list already.  The logic of this being that it doesn't make sense for people to show up in the user's list of people to be added when a request has been sent or they're already part of the directory. 2) The entries of with a confirmation of 1 or 2 must be removed from the

Comment: directory list.  So, it's like saying; show me the list of people of status 0 but remove them if those same people have a status of 1 or 2.

Comment: You could have edited your OP for this kind of elaboration :). I updated the answer to suit your need of eleminating users who have already been invited given a entry structure of (inviting_user, invited_user, 1).

Comment: PS: You can use `SELECT DISTINCT username`... it doesn't change the outcome (all users should be existent in both columns due to the (a,a,0) entry)

Comment: It seems to work!  Awesome!!!!  Okay, please help me understand this logic a bit.  When we say "select distinct contact from contacts where contact not in 
(select contact from contacts where username = '$valid_user')"

Comment: are we saying, perform the subquery first, then whatever output comes from it, do not include those entries in the main query?  I'll go change my OP settings :)

Comment: It means: walk through all users (distinct means once for each of them) and check if there is an entry for our currently iterated user in the form of (the_user_we_are_searching_new_friends_for, user_we_are_currently_iterating, anything) if there is, eleminate him from our suggested friends -- (csmith, csmith,0) will definitly eliminate himself, (csmith,x,1) will eleminate x (we did send a request to him) and (csmith,x,2) will eliminate x due to beeing a mutual friend -- if we cant find any of those, we can suggest him as new friend - please accept/upvote helpfull answers/comments on so :)

Comment: Thank you, Xevelion.  It doesn't seem like such a complicated thing now, and the rest of my site was harder to put together than this piece.  I was just spinning my wheels on this.  Your help is much appreciated.